# Skype screen sharing option missing

Tags: skype, desktop-sharing

I'm having a problem with Skype screen sharing. The option is missing. I read similar questions and:

1. vino is installed. I tried enabling screen sharing and activating it to no avail.
2. I tried disabling encryption for remote access even if this was not recommended.
3. I tried using Xorg instead of Wayland.
4. I tried using the .deb and snap versions (both the normal and preview versions) of Skype.

I don't know if it is related, but I'm mentioning it because it may. The Gnome screen recorder (that should be activated through <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) doesn't work either. Maybe there's a common underlying cause.

Comment: I don't know what happened but the option appeared now. Maybe a restart was necessary after enabling screen sharing. But I thought I had done that already.

Comment: A search on the tag [skype] led me to http://askubuntu.com/questions/1216823 . 1) Do you use xorg or Wayland? 2) Have you enabled screen sharing as per http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/remote-access-ubuntu-16-04 ? 3) Did you configure vino Desktop Sharing before a reboot as per help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#vino 4) Did you reboot after first enabling screen sharing, then try Skype? Please click [edit] & let us know if you've done these steps which helped other users; adding more data into the question is your channel to us. Please don't use Add Comment (our channel to you).