# Can't see shared screen in Skype

Tags: 16.04, skype

I am using Skype v8.57.0.116 in Ubuntu 16.04. Neither via the Skype app, nor via the Skype web interface can I see the screen shared by other persons in meetings. Sharing my screen appears to work fine.

Comment: A search on the tag [skype] https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/skype led me to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216823/skype-screen-sharing-option-missing so may I ask if you use xorg or Wayland? Have you enabled screen sharing before starting Skype as per http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/remote-access-ubuntu-16-04/ ? Did you reboot after first enabling screen sharing, then try Skype? Please click [edit] & let us know if you've done these which helped other Xenial users; adding more data into the question is your channel to us. Please don't use Add Comment (our channel to you).

Comment: Oh, yes please configure vino Desktop Sharing before that reboot as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#vino